# Using Binding<Double> type created from @Binding var X: String does not update UI SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, binding

I pass in a binding using an initializer like so:

```
let placeholderString: String
let imageName: String
let keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
let fieldType: DataFieldType
@Binding var fieldName: String // This var here.
private var isFocused: FocusState<Bool>.Binding
@State private var frame = CGRect.zero


init(placeholderString: String, imageName: String, keyboardType: UIKeyboardType, fieldType: DataFieldType, fieldName: Binding<String>, focusState: FocusState<Bool>.Binding) {
    self.placeholderString = placeholderString
    self.imageName = imageName
    self.keyboardType = keyboardType
    self.fieldType = fieldType
    self._fieldName = fieldName // This var here.
    self.isFocused = focusState
}
```

I uss the String binding on a textfield which works fine.

I create a custom binding that produces a Binding Double like so:

```
    private var doubleBinding: Binding<Double?> {

    get {
        guard let binding = Double(fieldName) else { return .constant(nil) }
        return .constant(binding)
    }
    set {
        guard let double = newValue.wrappedValue else { return }
        fieldName = String(double)
    }
}
```

I'm using this textfield with a custom textfield built in UIKit that takes a Binding Double in its initializer.

My problem is that whenever I dismiss the keyboard the values that I entered disappear and I'm left with whatever was initially loaded in the textfield when the view first appeared. See below.

I've tried passing the binding from a @State Double and it seemed to work fine so I figure it must be an issue with how I've setup the custom binding.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Don't use `.constant` outside of previews, there is no use for it. If you have a spot for `.constant` you might as well just use a `let`. `Binding` is by definition a two-way connection. if there is nothing to receive the changes what is the point of having the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Had to use this syntax.

```
    private var doubleBinding: Binding<Double?> { Binding(

    get: {
        guard let binding = Double(fieldName) else { return nil }
        return binding
    },
    set: {
        fieldName = String($0!)
    })
}
```

Not sure why the other syntax didn't work.  If anyone has some info on why this works and the other didn't please post a comment.